Illegal pattern character: n while reading yaml
I have a yaml with the following definition, but on reading the file i am getting an error  # Error: Failed while running read report config.
Illegal pattern character: n
  - source: internal
    instance: internal
    query: "select distinct b.HSETTLEDATE,a.ACCOUNT_NO,a.FREEZE_STATUS,a.DESCRP,a.FREEZE_MARK_UNMARK_DT,a.NARRATION,a.EXTENDED_NARR from Demo2 a left join Demo1 b on a.ACCOUNT_NO=INT(b.ACC_NO)"
    fetch_size: 10000
    partition: 1
    df_name: 'monthly_report_for_dbt_freeze_account_error'
    output_file_type: excel
    delimiter: na
    output_flag: T
    output_location: ""
    output_filename: "monthly_report_for_dbt_freeze_account_error"



this query is syntactically correct - not sure what the error is here...

Update - while the error reads that the issue is in the read config , it is on execution of the query - the error was caused by previous blocks of the yaml
the error arises when the date format is nor parseable by spark
please check the to_date statements in your code
steps to follow

run each query (print the dataframe created)
check the date formats for each query


Please add updates to the question itself, not as an answer
